# How do I stop default SET statements?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

When I run SQL profiler and issue queries using ADO.Net, I see these statements in SQL profiler:

```
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

I never wrote any of these statements in any query. How do I stop these Set statements? Does SQL server make a separate request just to set these SET statements?

Two questions:

1. Would it be better to turn off all of these SET statements? If yes, then how can I do it?
2. Which are the optimum settings for these SET? I know arithabort should be on since it gives performance boost in most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are being set by your client driver, so will always be set on new connections you create.

1. It would not be better to turn all of these off. Even though these are set when your connection is opened, it doesn't mean you can't override them by executing a set SQL statement on your connection, like the ones above.
2. I would set ARITHABORT on, as this set option is one of the ones used for indexes on computed columns and indexed views. You could change dateformat/language if your not American, but this doesn't matter a whole deal, and could be done at the login level. If you don't want to use READ_COMMITTED isolation, you could change this, though this is fine in most cases, hence it's the default. The rest look fine.